# Переменная типа boolean в условии останавливает выполнение программы. Почему?

Tags: java, условия

Мне нужно в качестве задания написать простенькую программу по условиям игры "Жизнь".
Все значения поля у меня хранятся в массиве булевых значений.
Мной был написан метод, который проверяет ячейки вокруг клетки по разным условиям и увеличивает счётчик +1 если находит "живую" (true) ячейку. КРоме условий расположения естественно есть условие которое берёт значение из массива. И если это значение false то исполнение почему-то останавливается и дальше не идёт.
В примере ниже **"1" не будет выведен в консоль и программа не завершиться** (так и будет висеть чего-то ждать) если fieldLikeBooArray[length - width + point] примет значение false:

```
public int checkPointsAround(int point, int width, boolean[] fieldLikeBooArray){
    int alivePointsAround = 0;
    int length = fieldLikeBooArray.length;
    int count = 0;
    if (count == 0 && point - width < 0 && fieldLikeBooArray[length - width + point]) alivePointsAround++;                                                            //верхний сосед первая строка
    else if (count == 0 && fieldLikeBooArray[point - width]) alivePointsAround++;                                                                              //верхний сосед остальные строки
    System.out.println(1);
    return alivePointsAround;}
```

Почему?
При этом если разбить это на два отдельных условия (что кажется очень кривым), то работает.
Пример:

```
if (point - width < 0) {
    if (fieldLikeBooArray[length - width + point]) alivePointsAround++;                                                            //верхний сосед первая строка
    }
else if (fieldLikeBooArray[point - width]) alivePointsAround++;
System.out.println(1);
```

Возможно вопрос предельно простой, но я уже вторые сутки не могу понять где ошибся. Help!
При необходимости могу выложить весь код.

Comment: Условие никак не может остановить выполнение программы. И расставляйте фигурные скобки в теле условия, это помогает не делать ошибок

Comment: Да. Абсолютно согласен. Условие не должно на это влиять. Они либо выполняется. Либо нет. А программа выполняется дальше. Но тут почему-то не так. Если fieldLikeBooArray = true, то пролетает, а если false, то дальше не исполняется... и вывода "1" не происходит. Замечание по скобкам я принимаю, но в данной ситуации на результат это не влияет.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже я понял в чём ошибка. Неправильно брать часть поля в качестве условия выполнения. Т.к. из-за этого он от частного случая (если ячейка "false") переходит к общему и там падает с ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Почему программа не завершается и ошибка не падает в консоль - для меня загадка.